# In mastermind game of 4 pegs and 6 colors , how first query of 5 non-equivalent queries is calculated?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, combinatorics

I am trying to build a generic ( **any no. of pegs and color**)  mastermind solver . It is mentioned at a lot of articles (Kenji Koyama; TW Lai. An optimal Mastermind strategy) I found after doing some search that for a 4 pegs , 6 color mastermind game , there are 5 non-equivalent queries in 1296 possible codes ie. **0000, 0001 , 0011, 0012, 0123** .But no where it is mentioned as how this was calculated ?

Question 1) If I have to find this non-equivalent list for any combination of pegs and color ( for example 5,6 or 6,9 ) , what should be the approach ?

Questions 2) Is there an existing algo or library which I can use or look at to get some ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Knuth gave a solution to this problem. It's too big to show as an answer here, but I discuss the theory and give an implementation at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/11/20/master-mind-part-2/).

Comment: Thanks for the blog . It was very useful in getting a better understanding of Knuth's alog. From your blog, if you can plz elaborate, as what could be a generic algo for getting the initial probes  "There are essentially five possible starting probes: 1 1 1 1, 1 1 1 2, 1 1 2 2, 1 1 2 3, and 1 2 3 4 (rotations are excluded, as are variants that substitute one symbol consistently for another)"

Comment: @user448810 - And what should be the generic approach to find the initial probes for larger values of c ( colors ) and p ( pegs ) ?

Comment: Do exactly what it says. Make a list of all possible permutations. Exclude rotations and variants that substitute one symbol consistently for another.

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm is to start with all of 1 color.
That will tell you exactly how many of that color exists in the solution.

If you get zero matches, continue selecting all one color until you have at least one match.
We will call it color1

Now, Put one color in position 1, and fill the rest with another color.
If you get two matches (2 little black pegs in the game), you know that color1 is in the correct position.
If you get two near matches (2 little white pegs in the game), you know that color1 does not go in position 1.

repeat the same procedure, using color 1 in positions 2 .. 4 using a new color each time.

Once you get to position 4 you know the positions for all of the color1s and you know all of the other colors.

There are at most 2 other solutions to try, which is well under the limit of 10 guesses

Answer (score 0):

Check the internet for the term "integer partitions". It is a fundamental mathematical term in combinatorics. What you are looking for is the "partition function" p(n). Here an example in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// recursive function calculates the partitions of n
int part(int n, int level = 0) {
  static vector<int> v(n);
  static int pcount;
  int first;

  if (n < 1) return 0; // end of recursion
  v[level] = n;

  // comment next lines out, if you are only intereseted
  // in the total number
  cout << pcount << ". ";
  for (int i = level; i >= 0; --i)
    cout  << v[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;

  pcount++;
  first = (level == 0) ? 1 : v[level - 1];

  for (int i = first; i <= n / 2; i++) {
    v[level] = i;
    part(n - i, level + 1); 
  }
  return pcount;
}

int main() {
  int pegs = 5; // change this for other mastermind var.
  cout << "p(" << pegs << ") = " << part(pegs) << endl;
}
```

It's assumed that the numbers of colors is equal or greater than the number of pegs.

If you are more a computer scientist, check Vol. 4a from Knuth's TAoCP, it's worth. However, the algorithm in there is something that I would  - nowadays - not consider as beeing artfully. But it's MIX ;-)